# In Play 2 Framework , how can I include git commit sha in sbt dist package name?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, sbt

I have a Play 2.2.x project, for which I can create universal distribution zip archive:

```
$ sbt dist
```

This creates a file `target/universal/project-name-1.0-SHAPSHOT.zip`

I want to include a git commit sha such that the package generated looks like this:

```
target/universal/project-name-1.0-SHAPSHOT-0d6d7f4325de87df6a8f46bd635d14ba8892715a.zip
```

In Play 2 Framework , how can I include git commit sha in sbt dist package name?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Easiest way is:

```
version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT-" + "git rev-parse HEAD".!!.trim
```